# How thick (in molecules) would a piece of paper be if it was folded to the moon?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, estimation

Apparently you can fold a piece of paper 42 times and reach the moon! 42 is the answer the everything after all! Oh, Douglas Adams, you clever son of a bitch.

The reasoning behind this is that as you fold a paper, it becomes twice as thick. It's exponential and can be modeled by the following formula for a paper that is say- 0.001 cm thick.

0.001(2)^42 = space travel

I want to test this. You have to figure that as you fold a paper and it becomes twice as thick, the area is also halfed. So, for a standard piece of A4 paper, being 8.5x11, would have an area of 92 in^2 or about 603 cm^2. The equivalent decrease in area can be modeled by this formula:

603(0.5)^42

Now, for the number of molecules in a sheet of paper. The number of molecules for a piece of paper consisting solely of cellulose (C6H10O5) strains can be found by using the molar mass of cellulose and the mass of the paper in question. So the calculations for a standard piece of A4 paper with a mass of 5 grams should look something like this:

5g ×  (1 mol C_6 H_10 O_5)/162g  =3.09 × 〖10〗^(-2)  mol      damn stackexchange formatting

And since a mole of cellulose contains 6.022 x 10^23 molecules, you would have about:

1.8586 x 10^22 molecules in that piece of paper

This is where that math breaks down, I've tried to divide the number of molecules by the resulting area, but the answer doesn't seems quite right. :/

Comment: 0.001 cm times $2^{42}$ gets you 11% of the way to the Moon...

Comment: cellulose is a polymer; there is no specific molar mass, but it would be on the order of 1000 times greater than what is suggested in the OP

Answer (score 1):

The area of your paper is lets A x B (measured in meters) and it has a thickness L

every time you fold across the A side the A side gets cut in half and the thickness doubles (For the most part). Likewise if you fold across teh B side that gets cut in half and the thickness doubles.

We have 2 problems here:

1. Can the paper you mentioned even be folded 42 times in the first place? or will we run out of atoms to do so.
2. After figuring out if it can be folded now we need to find the thickness.

I read from some article on google that cellulose has a length (or width? I'm not sure) of roughly 100 Angstroms = 1 x 10^(-8) meters ---> if you have 10^22 of these suckers you can cover a distance on the order of 10^(14) meters which is more than enough to make it to the moon about 1,000,000 times back and forth. So that much is covered.

Now lets say you folded it 42 times we alternate between short and long side for our folds to keep the paper as close to its original shape as possible, of course our folds will cease to folds after like 5 tries and turn into attempts to curl the paper but lets SUSPEND THE LAWS OF PHYSICS for the meanwhile and just imagine we can repeatedly perfectly fold the thing.

We have 2^(42)*0.001 cm = 2^(42)*0.001*0.01 m/cm = Not nearly enough

So you need more folds. I think 3-4 more folds should do the trick

Now notice when you fold you won't be folding the same side over and over but ideally alternating so...

The dimenasions are

$$\frac{height}{2^{n/2}}  \frac{width}{2^{n/2}}$$

given n folds. In our case n = 46.

Comment: So, using the new and improved area formula, I found there to be 264,098,784 molecules in the new area.

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: @user3203833 if you find an answer to any of your questions you post feel free to give it an upvote (the up arrow), if you dislike give it a downvote (the down arrow) and if its what you need then click the green check